# Story with its own states and methods

Tags: storybook, angular-storybook

To demonstrate a component I try to write custom state and methods for a story.

For example, I have a component ListItems who accepts an array of string as Input.

In the story of this component I want to show an interactive example of the usage of this component.

So my story will have internal state "items" and internal method "addItem"

I know how to do that with React, but I'm stuck with Angular.

### Here is a React way to do that:

([View in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-storybook-story-with-internal-state-and-method-71740902-wj5x67?file=/src/components/ListItems.stories.tsx))

```js
// ListItems.tsx
import React from "react";
export type ListItemsProps = { items: string[] };
export const ListItems = ({ items = [] }: ListItemsProps) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item, key) => (
        <li key={key}>{item}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

```js
// ListItems.stories.tsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ListItems } from "./ListItems";

export default {
  title: "ListItems",
  component: ListItems
};

export const Text = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(["Demo Item"]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const addItem = () => {
    setItems([...items, value]);
    setValue("");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <ListItems items={items} />
      <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
      <input type="submit" onClick={addItem} value="add" />
    </div>
  );
};

};
```

### How can I write the same story with following Angular Component ?

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-list-items",
  template: `<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>`
})
export default class ListItems implements OnInit {
  @Input() items: string[] = [];
  constructor(){}
  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution on Angular, but it's not an elegant one...

Maybe someone know a better way !

And I can't find a solution to show the code story template on "Show code" feature.

```js
import { Story, Meta } from '@storybook/angular/types-6-0';
import { ListItemsComponent } from './list-items.component';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export default {
    title: 'Demo/ListItems',
    component: ListItemsComponent,
} as Meta;

const Template: Story<ListItemsComponent> = (args: ListItemsComponent) => ({ 
    props:args,
});
export const BasicDemo = Template.bind({})
BasicDemo.args={
    items: ["Basic Demo", "Without interaction"]
}

// Create a dedicated component for the interactive story
@Component({
    selector: 'story-list-items',
    template: `
        <core-list-items [items]="items"></core-list-items>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" /><button (click)="addItem()">add</button>
    `,
})
class InteractiveDemoComponent{
    items = [];
    value: string = '';
    addItem(){
        this.items = [...this.items, this.value];
        this.value = ""
    }
}
const InteractiveTemplate: Story<ListItemsComponent> = (args: ListItemsComponent) => ({ 
    props:args,
    component: InteractiveDemoComponent,
});
export const InteractiveDemo = InteractiveTemplate.bind({});
InteractiveDemo.args = {
    items: ["Interactive Demo"]
}
```